# How to check if inside a modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a generic piece of html code with form fields which I reuse in several places. When opened inside a bootstrap modal I would like the content to fill the entire modal, but when used elsewhere I don't want it to be as wide. I wanted to do this using ng-class, using code like this:

```
<div ng-class="modal ? 'col-sm-9' : ['col-sm-9 col-lg-5']">
   content...
</div>
```

The problem is: how do I check if the code is inside a modal or not? Is there some function I can call or some variable to read? I would like to avoid populating all modal-controllers with some isModal() function.

Comment: can't you add your own class and write a css rule for this based on `.modalClass .myClass`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using CSS for this.  The browser would then identify if the snip-it appears within an element defined as the modal and the correctly apply the style.

Assuming you are using LESS with your bootstrap implementation an example is below.  But it should give you a general idea either way.

**LESS CSS markup:**

```
div.content {
     .col-lg-5
}

modal {
     div.content {
          .col-sm-9;
     }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="modal">
         <h1>Heading</h1>
         <div class="content"> 
              content...
         </div> 
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Give `id= "mymodal"` to the `div`.
Then in script create a click function and call this `div` by `id` :

```
    $("#mymodal").show();
```

The modal shows with its content.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with AngularJS